# Problem with richhtmlfield

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a problem with a new `RichHtmlField`.

I Have a page layout with old `RichHtmlField`. the old one is working fine.

I created a new field. after I deploy the solution to my dev environment it works fine, but when I try to publish it to another server (with wsp file), the HTML field does not exist. I can see the div that wraps the `RichHtmlField`, but when I edit the page the item is not there.

can someone please help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Check if this RichHtmlField have a style that not located at the other server

Comment: Hi,you mean css file?

Comment: the style of this field that is located in your CSS file, if not have style check the CSS linked to the site

Comment: i didn't give the item any css style. just the div that wrap it. but when i  check it on the other environment the div gets the style.

Comment: Ok try to match your destination with your source field also is the DIV have a style ?

Comment: yes, but just padding, not something serious. i tried to match the setting of this new field to the old one, and everything seems to be same.

Comment: don't forget to copy also the style of this field from the source to your web part or to CSS located to the destination farm

Comment: the file was copied with the deployment file. i can see it with developer tools (f12).

Comment: are you have customized master page

Comment: yes. do i need to check something there?

Comment: not now , but  try to remove the class style of the source field that working properly in dev , then deploy it on dev and check first if the issue related to style or something else

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43268/discussion-on-question-by-ben-problem-with-richhtmlfield).

Comment: Please post your latest edit as an answer instead so your can resolve the question

Answer (score 0):

Update - The Problem was solved, after removing the field from the setting of the library. The problem occur because the filed name was not in English, so the  field name in the url ("field=...") was in gibberish. after removing and reloading the column again, the problem solved.

Thank you